# nginx reverse proxy best way to redirect

Tags: nginx

regarding about increasing nginx reverse proxy performance
should i use 
proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
or 
proxy_pass http://domain-name.tld:8080
which one will be faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the IP it will be faster since you don't have to resolve the domain, but in long term probably you would like to use the domain since gives you the flexibility to change the IP is pointing to without need modify your existing configuration.

The performance increase would be minimal, probably will not even notice, but is also something that could be fine tuned better using a DNS cache in favor of having a flexible configuration instead of hard coded values.

Also, take a look at this article https://tenzer.dk/nginx-with-dynamic-upstreams/ explains more in detail some issues when using domain names instead of IP's but again, this depends on your setup.